# When is possible to add a team to "My Desired Team"?

Tags: pro-evolution-soccer-2011

I'm playing BAL mode.I'm on the first year of a 3 years contract with FC Twente and I have the third agent (100,000). When I'm searching for a club, it seems I can't add them to "My desired team" list so that my agent will start negotiations.

When is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible only when the transfer window is open. In real life, the summer transfer window for the Eredivisie seems to run from July 1 through August 31 or September 1, and the winter transfer window runs from January 1 through January 31. If you aren't currently in a transfer window, you may not be able to ask your agent to start negotiations with a team.

Comment: I'll let you know if is that the case.